# SECUGEN sdk matching the every finger template

Tags: android, fingerprint, template-matching

I am using secugen sdk for getting fingerprints using secugen hamster plus fingerprint device.

In there documentation they mentioned for fingerprint matching you've to save templates and then match them afterwards for verification purposes.

Now if I get new fingerprint template and match it with saved template it matches the template regardless of which finger I use

Please help

Note: I am not posting any code because I've hardly done anything new I was just using its sdk provided functionality

Comment: have you find any solutions yet? secugen technical team doesnt reply on my email it seems there not helping and there api doesnt have a documentation

Comment: @MaryDaisySanchez No didnt't found any solutions yet. And yes they are not replying and they have a pathetic documentation :(

Comment: i was hoping they can have a good technical support that we can rely on there seems to be not into it